# PHP - Smarty Variables unset after header redirect

Tags: php, smarty

I have a php file (form.php) that uses a template (form.htm) to display a form. The template file's form action is form.php. If the form is incomplete when submitted, I want to redirect back to the form WITHOUT losing information that the user has already input.

I'm setting smarty variables using t->assign('varname', $_POST['var']) and setting the form values to these variables ( value="{$varname}" ), however when redirected using php's header() function, these Smarty variables are lost (which I've confirmed using Smarty {debug}).

Does anyone have any idea of how to make it so that these variables aren't unset when using a header redirect? Thanks!

Comment: When redirecting you esentially tell the browser to request a different page, so you lose all the stuff you had in the previous request. You can share data  between requests using sessions.

Comment: I thought that'd be the case - so there's no way of using smarty template variables instead of session variables in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smarty is only template engine, so you cannot do here more than in PHP.

But in your case you said you want to make header redirect after sending form (to be honest I have no idea why you want to do it. In normal case you simple set action in form and in controller you simple check data and if they are valid you do what you want - for example send email and if they are not valid you simple show the form again - that's it).

However if you really need to do this that way, what you can do is to use session data and save all data from post to session, make redirection and use that from session to display in Smarty.

So in PHP you can do:

```
$_SESSION['post_data'] = $_POST;
// now you make redirection
```

And in file you handle redirection you can simple do:

```
$smarty->assign('post_data',$SESSION['post_data']);
unset($SESSION['post_data']);
```

And in template file you can then use:

```
{$post_data.var}
```

**EDIT**

But as I said normally you do it this way in PHP file:

```
  $isValid = false; 

  if (isset($_POST['submit']) {
     $isValid = validateData($_POST);

     if ($isValid) {
          // do something here - for example send email
     }
     else {
         $smarty->assign('error', 'There were errors in your form. Try again');
     }
  } 
  $smarty->assign('is_valid',$isValid);
```

And in Smarty you do:

```
{if $isValid}
   form was sent
{else}
   {if isset($error)}{$error}{/if}
   you display form here
{/if}
```

Comment: Ah, I think this is exactly what I'm looking for - overcomplicating things! Smarty is all new to me (I'm working with someone else's code). Thanks Marcin!

Answer (score 1):

Don't redirect the user. Just redraw the form. In general, this HTTP workflow should be used when dealing with forms:

1. `GET /form.php` - Display the form to the user
2. `POST /form.php` - Process the form input

   1. If the form input is invalid, send back `form.php`
   2. If the form input is valid, save to the database, *now* redirect the user

So basically you have:

1. GET
2. POST (invalid input from the user)
3. POST (valid input from the user)
4. REDIRECT

Comment: Sorry - I'm relatively new to this. Could you elaborate a little on "redraw the form"? Basically, what I'm doing currently is redirecting back to the form page again (header('Location: form.php');).